# how to get data from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

List the name of students who enroll in both course ‘CS-204’ and course ‘CS-102’

```
table1:enroll
student id , code, grade
table2:student
student id ,name ,bdate,address
```

..................................
 i try as

```
select student.name,enrol.code from student,enrol where code='CS-204' or code='CS-102'
```

Comment: You'd better check out JOIN!

Answer (score 0):

You have to join both tables:

```
select student.name,enrol.code 
from student join enrol on student.student_id=enrol.student_id 
where code='CS-204' and student.student_id in (
   select student.name,enrol.code 
   from student join enrol on student.student_id=enrol.student_id  
   where code='CS-102'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables

```
SELECT s.name, e.code
FROM student s
INNER JOIN enroll e ON s.student_id = e.student_id
WHERE e.code='CS-204' OR e.code='CS-102'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more parameter to WHERE clause:

```
SELECT student.name, enroll.code 
FROM student, enroll 
WHERE (student.student_id=enroll.student_id) AND (enroll.code='CS-204' OR enroll.code='CS-102')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this.

```
Select student.name from student join enroll
on student.student_id = enroll.student_id where 
enroll.code in ('CS-204','CS-102');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the name of students from both courses this way:

```
SELECT b.name as student_name 
FROM enroll a, student b 
WHERE (a.student_id=b.student_id) AND (a.code='CS-204' or a.code='CS-102'`)
```